# Sound not working, no soundcard detected 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

So apparently my PC did some updates which change things around a little bit. I can get used to it but the sound is not working any more.

From what I've seen online I've tried installing alsa drivers, to no avail.

I then launched the "ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64", which gave me the following output [here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HJ3RrN0y)

From what I understand no soundcard was detected. Any idea how I can get it to work again?

Edit: I should probably add that `lspci -v` does not turn up any "Audio Device"